# SFML event loop performance issues

Tags: c++, graphics, sfml

```
int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1280,720), "Game");

    window.setActive(false);

    std::thread gameThread(game, &window);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

    }

    gameThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm making a basic game loop, and I noticed that every second or so the frametime will spike, sometimes up to 50 ms for a frame or two. I realized that when I comment out `while (window.pollEvent(event))`, the stuttering stops. Could this be a bug with SFML, or am I just doing something wrong?

Platform - Windows 10

Compiler - MSVC 2015

SFML version - 2.4.0

I got the frametime measurements by writing

```
Time elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime();  
Int64 frameTime = elapsedTime.asMicroseconds() - oldTime.asMicroseconds();              
fps.setString(std::to_string(frameTime));
oldTime = elapsedTime;
```

into the loop

EDIT - Now the issue persists no matter whether the event loop is commented out or not. Which is strange, because that definitely wasn't the case yesterday.

Comment: It's hard to say at that point. It could be a sync problem, since I see a `std::thread` which interacts with the window. Profile your program and see what is the point which delays you app.

Comment: That thread was me trying to get around the issue by running everything else in a separate thread - which actually helped somewhat. Even without a separate thread the issue remains. I'm just confused because everything else works fine if the event loop is removed.

Comment: Have you tried to slow down the *main thread* inserting a `sleep(...)` of some milliseconds just to avoid to consume a lots of CPU cycles

Comment: I just tried that - All it does is make event handling laggy, and didn't stop the stuttering. EDIT: It does stop a lot of the stuttering to be fair, but that's just because the event loop isn't executing for a time. There still is stuttering whenever it does run the event loop.

Comment: Add some details to your question,like: *platform, compiler, library version, how did you get the tick measure*, it sure will help!